# References in Rmarkdown: use title capitalization as is in the .bib file

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bibtex, bibliography, csl

I'm writing a manuscript using Rmarkdown with RStudio and `knitr`. To format the references, I'm using the `.csl` file for the journal *Global Ecology and Biogeography*, which I got from https://www.zotero.org/styles.

My problem is that the titles are automatically transformed to sentence case. This is especially problematic for species names, which become lower case.

For example,

```
Two types of morphophysiological dormancy in seeds of two genera (Osmorhiza and Erythronium) with an Arcto-Tertiary distribution pattern
```

becomes

```
Two types of morphophysiological dormancy in seeds of two genera (osmorhiza and erythronium) with an arcto-tertiary distribution pattern
```

According to this question: [How to set references to 'sentence case'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614125/how-to-set-references-to-sentence-case), I should remove from the `.csl` file all lines like `text-case=`. The problem is that there are no such lines, and still my titles are transformed.

For a bonus, I would also like to know how to keep species names in italics.

**Rmarkdown file**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
bibliography: refs.bib
csl: global-ecology-and-biogeography.csl
link-citations: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

[@RN1045]

# References
````

**refs.bib file with the bibliography**

```
@article{RN1045,
   author = {Baskin, Carol C.; Meyer, Susan E.; Baskin, Jerry M.},
   title = {Two types of morphophysiological dormancy in seeds of two genera (Osmorhiza and Erythronium) with an Arcto-Tertiary distribution pattern},
   journal = {American Journal of Botany},
   volume = {82},
   number = {3},
   pages = {293-298},
   ISSN = {00029122},
   DOI = {10.1002/j.1537-2197.1995.tb12633.x},
   url = {<Go to ISI>://WOS:A1995QM77500001; https://bsapubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/j.1537-2197.1995.tb12633.x},
   year = {1995},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

**global-ecology-and-biogeography.csl file with the style**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style xmlns="http://purl.org/net/xbiblio/csl" class="in-text" version="1.0" demote-non-dropping-particle="sort-only" default-locale="en-US">
  <info>
    <title>Global Ecology and Biogeography</title>
    <id>http://www.zotero.org/styles/global-ecology-and-biogeography</id>
    <link href="http://www.zotero.org/styles/global-ecology-and-biogeography" rel="self"/>
    <link href="http://www.zotero.org/styles/bioinformatics" rel="template"/>
    <link href="http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/%28ISSN%291466-8238/homepage/ForAuthors.html" rel="documentation"/>
    <author>
      <name>Bernhard Hoiß</name>
      <email>bernhard.hoiss@uni-wuerzburg.de</email>
    </author>
    <category citation-format="author-date"/>
    <category field="biology"/>
    <issn>1466-822X</issn>
    <eissn>1466-8238</eissn>
    <summary>The Global Ecology and Biogeography style</summary>
    <updated>2016-09-10T14:32:31+00:00</updated>
    <rights license="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License</rights>
  </info>
  <locale>
    <terms>
      <term name="edition" form="short">edn.</term>
      <term name="editor" form="verb-short">ed. by</term>
      <term name="translator" form="verb-short">trans.</term>
    </terms>
  </locale>
  <macro name="editor">
    <names variable="editor" delimiter=",">
      <label form="verb-short" prefix=" (" suffix=" "/>
      <name sort-separator=", " and="text" initialize-with="." delimiter=", " suffix=")"/>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="author">
    <names variable="author">
      <name name-as-sort-order="all" and="symbol" sort-separator=", " initialize-with="." delimiter=", " delimiter-precedes-last="never"/>
      <label form="short" prefix=" "/>
      <substitute>
        <names variable="editor"/>
        <text variable="title"/>
      </substitute>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="author-short">
    <names variable="author">
      <name form="short" and="symbol" delimiter=", " initialize-with=". "/>
      <et-al term="et-al" font-style="italic"/>
      <substitute>
        <names variable="editor"/>
        <names variable="translator"/>
        <text variable="title"/>
      </substitute>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="title">
    <text variable="title"/>
  </macro>
  <macro name="publisher">
    <group delimiter=", ">
      <text variable="publisher"/>
      <text variable="publisher-place"/>
    </group>
  </macro>
  <macro name="year-date">
    <date variable="issued">
      <date-part name="year"/>
    </date>
  </macro>
  <macro name="edition">
    <choose>
      <if is-numeric="edition">
        <group delimiter=" ">
          <number variable="edition" form="ordinal"/>
          <text term="edition" form="short"/>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else>
        <text variable="edition" suffix="."/>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <citation et-al-min="3" et-al-use-first="1" disambiguate-add-year-suffix="true" collapse="year-suffix" year-suffix-delimiter=",">
    <sort>
      <key macro="year-date"/>
      <key macro="author-short"/>
    </sort>
    <layout prefix="(" suffix=")" delimiter="; ">
      <group delimiter=", ">
        <text macro="author-short"/>
        <text macro="year-date"/>
        <text variable="locator"/>
      </group>
    </layout>
  </citation>
  <bibliography hanging-indent="true" entry-spacing="0">
    <sort>
      <key macro="author"/>
      <key variable="title"/>
    </sort>
    <layout suffix=".">
      <text macro="author"/>
      <date variable="issued" prefix=" (" suffix=")">
        <date-part name="year"/>
      </date>
      <choose>
        <if type="bill book graphic legal_case legislation motion_picture report song" match="any">
          <group delimiter=" " prefix=" ">
            <text macro="title" font-style="italic" suffix=","/>
            <text macro="edition"/>
            <text macro="editor"/>
            <text macro="publisher"/>
          </group>
        </if>
        <else-if type="chapter paper-conference" match="any">
          <text macro="title" prefix=" " suffix="." font-style="italic"/>
          <group prefix=" " suffix=",">
            <text variable="container-title" font-style="italic"/>
            <text variable="collection-title" prefix=" " suffix="."/>
            <text macro="editor"/>
          </group>
          <group suffix=".">
            <group prefix=" " suffix=".">
              <label variable="page" suffix=" " form="short"/>
              <text variable="page"/>
            </group>
            <text macro="publisher" prefix=" "/>
          </group>
        </else-if>
        <else>
          <text macro="title" prefix=" " suffix="."/>
          <group delimiter=", " prefix=" " suffix=".">
            <text variable="container-title" form="long" font-style="italic"/>
            <text variable="volume" font-weight="bold"/>
            <text variable="page"/>
          </group>
        </else>
      </choose>
    </layout>
  </bibliography>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `knitr` uses `pandoc-citeproc` for citation rendering, and that you can preserve casing by using another set of brackets around the title. See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/issues/269.

So instead of

```
title = {Two types of morphophysiological dormancy in seeds of two genera (Osmorhiza and Erythronium) with an Arcto-Tertiary distribution pattern}
```

you'd use

```
title = {{Two types of morphophysiological dormancy in seeds of two genera (Osmorhiza and Erythronium) with an Arcto-Tertiary distribution pattern}}
```

See also https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/blob/master/man/pandoc-citeproc.1.md#titles-title-vs-sentence-case,

For species names, try `\textit{Osmorhiza}`. (per https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21255)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. For those (like me) generating the `.bib` file from an EndNote library, I will add that you can edit the BibTeX export style of EndNote so it inserts the double {{}} in your titles to protect them from alteration of capitalization. You can also insert the `\textit{Osmorhiza}` in your EndNote reference to have the italics in the final document generated with `knitr`, but then it will appear like that if you want to use it in Word.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if you want capitalised *and* italicised species names is to wrap the species name in `{\emph{species name}}` in the title.

For example:

```
@article{berra1973,
   title = {A home range study of {\emph{Galaxias bongbong}} in Australia}
}
```

@Rintze Zelle's answer using double curly brackets is required to retain a capital 'A' in 'Australia' in this example.

I use Zotero as a citation manager and the Visual Editor in RStudio to lookup and populate a .bib file for a RMarkdown document, and if the species name is wrapped in `<i>species name</i>` in the title in Zotero, RStudio Visual Editor automatically replaces `<i>species name</i>` with `{\emph{species name}}` in the .bib file.

Comment: You are answering the question so please don't ask counter question in answer ?